# What is the normal process to fix two bug in git?

Tags: git, git-flow

For example, I'm now in `develop` branch, and have to fix two bugs,

so first I `git checkout -b hotfix/bug1`, and fix and commit and push to Github and pull request and wait for merge.

Where should I start to fix bug2?

1. in `hotfix/bug1`, then `git checkout -b hotfix/bug2`, and fix and commit and push?
2. `checkout develop` first and then `git checkout -b hotfix/bug2`, and fix and commit and push?

Comment: If the fix to bug2 is independent of the fix of bug1 I would do them in separate branches, so option 2.

Comment: It is independent, but maybe modify same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with #2. It will simplify your life if you branch off develop.

Getting into master will force the two bugs to be reconciled eventually with a merge.

Also remember, your two bug fixes might not get accepted as-is, so it's best to develop them as independently as possible.

Comment: If #2, when fix bug2, the bug1 is not fixed, is it ok when I try to merge bug1 and bug2 into develop later? because I maybe modify same file.

Comment: Yes. Merging them later is the best thing to do. Git forces you to do this and helps you along.

Comment: But if I will modify same file in these two bugs, won't it conflict when merge the two bug branches?

Comment: If there is a conflict (only if the same **lines** are changed), you will resolve the conflict at merge time in whatever branch you merge last. It's a simple process, nothing to be afraid of. Adding a `mergetool` will help a lot, but that's another story that's well covered here already.